# ColorAnimation, Completed event doesn't work more then once

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation, coloranimation

I have code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="KeysBorderBrush" Color="DimGray" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox Name="Keys" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,2,0,2" Width="122" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource KeysBorderBrush}" />
```

And codebehind:

```
    SolidColorBrush keysBorderBrush;
    ColorAnimation _keysAnimation;

    public Constructor()
    {
        _keysAnimation  = new ColorAnimation();
        _keysAnimation.Completed += _keysAnimation_Completed;
    }

    private void Active_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        keysBorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)this.FindResource("KeysBorderBrush");
        keysBorderBrush.Color = Colors.Black;

        _keysAnimation.To = Colors.Red;
        _keysAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
        _keysAnimation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2);
        _keysAnimation.DecelerationRatio = .1;
        _keysAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

        keysBorderBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, _keysAnimation);

    }
    void _keysAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        keysBorderBrush.Color = Colors.DimGray;
    }
```

My goal:
Set the color to black, then animate, then return color to gray in `_keysAnimation_Completed` event.

The problem in the `_keysAnimation_Completed` event handler, it doesn't whant set the color back to `DimGray`, it works just one time, in second+ times color stay in Black all of time, how can I fix it?

Comment: Try this: Resources["KeysBorderBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DimGray)

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but the animation did not work with a vanilla WPF `ComboBox` - it seems that the default control template of `ComboBox` does not respect the `BorderBrush` dependency property (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx). Did you modify the default control template? And when is the `Active_Checked` handler triggered?

Comment: Reza ArabQaeni, Yes, this variant works too, tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `_keysAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop`, it will work as you expect it to.

Your `Active_Checked` method should look like this:

```cs
private void Active_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _keysBorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush) FindResource("KeysBorderBrush");
    _keysBorderBrush.Color = Colors.Black;

    _keysAnimation.To = Colors.Red;
    _keysAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
    _keysAnimation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2);
    _keysAnimation.DecelerationRatio = .1;
    _keysAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
    _keysAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;

    _keysBorderBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, _keysAnimation);
}
```

Comment: Oh God, one line of code... This is exactly what I was looking for! Works like charm, tnx alot.